# What happen when call copy_backward in push_back?

Tags: c++, stl

I was recently looking at the source code for SGI STL.

And I know `vector.push_back` will call `insert_aux`, and `insert_aux` will call `copy_backward`.

```
void push_back(const T& x){
    ...
    insert_aux(end(),x);
}

void insert_aux(iterator position, const T& x){
    if (finish != end_of_storage) {
         ...
         ++finish;
         T x_copy = x;
         copy_backward(position, finish - 2, finish -1);
    }
    ...   
}
```

In the last sentence, as I understand it, `position` is `finish - 1`, so how can it call `back_backward` when (position > finish - 2)?

What will happen?

Comment: Totally OT, but I want to congratulate you on using the `stl` tag correctly. :)

Comment: @Some programmer dude Do you mean this call will do nothing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have omitted the important pieces of code.

```
void push_back(const Tp& x) {
    if (finish != end_of_storage) {
        construct(finish, x);
        ++_M_finish;
    }
    else
        insert_aux(end(), x);
}
```

`insert_aux` is called here only if `finish == end_of_storage`. If this condition is `true`, another branch is taken inside `insert_aux` to allocate new storage:

```
void insert_aux(iterator position, const Tp& x) {
    if (finish != end_of_storage) {
       ...
    } else {
        const size_type old_size = size();
        const size_type len = old_size != 0 ? 2 * old_size : 1;
        iterator new_start = allocate(len);
        iterator new_finish = new_start;
        new_finish = uninitialized_copy(start, position, new_start);
        construct(new_finish, x);
        ++new_finish;
        new_finish = uninitialized_copy(position, finish, new_finish);
        destroy(begin(), end());
        deallocate(start, end_of_storage - start);
        start = new_start;
        finish = new_finish;
        end_of_storage = new_start + len;
    }
}
```

The first branch in `insert_aux()` simply shifts the tail by one element to the right to make a vacant place for the element being inserted. This can only happen if we have enough room to accommodate it.

Answer (score 0):

Finish points to next to last element. In insert_aux function, after incrementing finish,  position is finish-2. So copy_backward copy from position to position at position+1.

Comment: Thank you the same! But I think the first answer is the right one.